# Angular matDatePicker not formatting correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a material date picker that functionally works just fine but has some styling issues. [image]

I would like the text "Choose a date" to show up on the left side of the calendar icon, as it does in this example: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
but as you can see it's like the calendar icon is pushed so far to the left that it shoves the text up.

Here is the html for this:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="col-md-6">
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate" (dateChange)="setMinEndDate($event)" [min]="today" [(ngModel)]="model.startDate">
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

I have no other CSS or HTML for this. The date picker does exist inside a container class but even if I put it outside, or in a blank html page it still looks like this. I then assumed it had to be something with global styling. My app.component.css is completely blank. In my src folder in style.css I do have the global styling for angular material: `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` which seems to make everything else angular-material related work properly. Deleting this does not solve my problem as a global theme is required.

I am using angular material version 11.2.13 and Angular Core version 11.2.14.

What else could be causing this problem? Let me know if you need me to share anything else.

Comment: Add a reproducible example. Otherwise, it's hard to debug what's wrong. The code should work just fine.

Comment: You've linked to the Angular Material v15 documentation, so you're looking at an example from v15 which is a complete redesign from v14. Which version are you using in your project?

Comment: @DM v-11.2.13, so that is quite possibly the reason. Thank you!

Comment: @DM Actually now that I've checked it looks like the code for v11 and v15 for the Datepicker hasn't changed.

Comment: @msrumon this is a reproducible example. I have given you all the information you need to recreate this to the best of my knowledge. The only other piece of information it lacks is what is wrong, which is the question.

Comment: A git repository was expected, with the minimal code showing only the problem you're having.

Comment: try remove the class "col-md-6", in the example of material angular version 11 looks like work. BTW, col-md-6 sound me a class of bootstrap, are you mixing material.css and bootstrap.css? I'm not pretty sure that there're conficts when you use both

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the directive in your toggle (matIconSuffix doesn't exist before material v15), in  try to use this

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

Comment: Nice that fixed it for me!